# How to set limit for EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

How can I set a limit of number on `EditText`?
Like maximum number it's 30, from 31 set a `Toast`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is an answer if you want to detect if there's more than 30 characters

First of all I recommend to you to set it on your `.xml` file as follows :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/someId"
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Then in your `onCreate()` you have to initialize it do it as follows :

```
EditText eText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.someId);
```

Now you have to add `Filters` to it as follows:

```
eText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { 
    new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30)
});
```

And finally you add a `TextWatcher()` to deal with it as follows:

```
    eText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(count >= 30) Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Max length of EditText is "+ String.valueOf(30), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

> There's an answer to detect if user tries to put a number higher than n

Your question is quite difficult to understand, but yes, finally I got you, you lucky that I did something similar a year ago...

You first create this `inner class` called `Max30TextWatcher` (or whatever name)

```
public class Max30TextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private EditText et;

        Max30TextWatcher(EditText et) {
            this.et = et;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editable.toString())){
                return;
            }
            try {
                if (Integer.valueOf(et.getText().toString()) > 30) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Max is 30 dawg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //put all the TextView ""
                    et.setText("");

                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                //no dots and comma accepted
                et.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
```

So you change the `.xml` to this :

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/someId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2" />
```

And you call the new class as follows :

```
et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.someId);
et.addTextChangedListener(new Max30TextWatcher(et));
```

And you are done, you cannot put a number higher than 30 :)

Happy coding!

Comment: For me is working @AdrianGeanta, make sure you have implemented the same code than me

Comment: It's work what?.. I just want to set a limit to 30 and stop there.. I don't want to set limit of characters. This code, I think it's for characters..

Comment: Yep... I can write 30 numbers in that edit text .. For characters I want a limit length 2.. And I know how to do this

Comment: I have a sample demo, and when I try to put 31 chars it doesn't type anything... show me your code

Comment: @AdrianGeanta was what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake :) Yes, the edit it's working perfect,thank you <3

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `onTextChangeListener` on `EditText` and inside `onTextChanged`, you can check if number entered is greater than 30 or not. If it is greater than 30, you can display the `Toast` with appropriate message and then clear the text of the `EditText`

Comment: this is a limit for how many characters i can put in edittext.. I want something else